# Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs

Tags: cocoa, app-store, entitlements

The control, I am using in the application are labels,buttons,Qwebkit,progressbar and some cocoa classes NSString,NSURL,NSDictionary,NSAppleEventDescriptor,CFStringRef,CFURLRef,FSRef,FSCatalogInfo,NSSting .   when I upload,no error but I get 'invalid binary' afterwards.  and receive a mail from apple developer with subject "Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check for deprecated APIs

Answer (score 2):

Apple no longer accepts submissions to the Mac App Store that use QuickTime or QTKit. The best way to find where you are using these API's is to remove the QuickTime and/or QTKit framework from your project. Generally you will need to replace the places you were using QuickTime API's with AVFoundation. This works very well on Mac OS X 10.7 and newer. Unfortunately there is no good solution if you want to support back to 10.6. You may also find that 3rd party frameworks rely on QuickTime API's, in which case you will need to check for updates from the developers.